# Winforms - How do I create a custom windows border and close/minimise buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, border

I am creating a C# WinForms application. I would like to have a Custom Form Border. And I want to create a black custom window (with border and controls) like that of Adobe Lightroom. For example -
[image: Border like Adobe Lightroom]
How do I create it, please help?

Comment: Here's the article to create custom windows forms using only panels  --        [Creating Custom Windows Forms in C# using Panels](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1068043/Creating-Custom-Windows-Forms-in-Csharp-using-Pane)

Answer (score 6):

If the custom-chrome tools don't provide you with the look-and-feel that you want, this kind of thing is easy to do yourself in C#.  Basically, you create a borderless form (FormBorderStyle = None) and then create all the controls and borders yourself, by placing controls where you need them (a label for the title bar, command buttons for close and minimize etc.) and/or drawing directly on the form's surface using the Graphics object.

You also have to implement code to allow the form to be dragged around by its "fake" title bar (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302680/custom-dialog-with-a-text-field-in-winmobile#305732) for a sample of how to do this).  You may also have to implement your own resizing mechanism (if you need the forms to be resizable).

Finally, although the custom-form code might be a bit clunky, you can implement it on a single form and then have all the other forms in your application inherit from this form, which makes it a very useful technique for custom-skinning an entire application.

Comment: Honestly a very fair approach

Answer (score 3):

My task was to make active window more noticeable, bright - than others, inactive windows of the app. App has many opened windows, some modal, some modeless - and the MDI parent one.

You can can use something like not-a-border - a frame inside the client area. Here is the code snippet, a part of a base class (can be used directly in a form):

```
    #region Кастомизированное поведение - рамки, активность и т.д.
    private bool isCurrentlyActive = false;
    private bool childControlsAreHandled = false;
    private Pen activeWindowFramePen, inactiveWindowFramePen;
    private Point[] framePoints;

    private void AddControlPaintHandler(Control ctrl)
    {
        ctrl.Paint += DrawWindowFrame;
        if (ctrl.Controls != null)
        {
            foreach (Control childControl in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                AddControlPaintHandler(childControl);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);
        if ((this.childControlsAreHandled == false)
            && (WindowFrameType != Forms.WindowFrameType.NoFrame)
            && (this.MdiParent == null))
        {
            RecalculateWindowFramePoints();
            AddControlPaintHandler(this);
            this.childControlsAreHandled = true;
        }

        this.isCurrentlyActive = true;
        if (InactiveWindowOpacity < 1)
        {
            base.Opacity = 1;
        }
        base.Invalidate(true);
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDeactivate(e);
        this.isCurrentlyActive = false;
        if (InactiveWindowOpacity < 1)
        {
            base.Opacity = InactiveWindowOpacity;
        }
        base.Invalidate(true);
    }

    protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResizeEnd(e);
        this.framePoints = null;
        RecalculateWindowFramePoints();
        this.Invalidate(true);
    }

    private Pen ActivePen
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.isCurrentlyActive)
            {
                if (this.activeWindowFramePen == null)
                {
                    this.activeWindowFramePen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb((int)(WindowFrameOpacity*255), WindowFrameActiveColor), WindowFrameSize * 2);
                }
                return this.activeWindowFramePen;
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.inactiveWindowFramePen == null)
                {
                    this.inactiveWindowFramePen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb((int)(WindowFrameOpacity*255), WindowFrameInactiveColor), WindowFrameSize * 2);
                }
                return this.inactiveWindowFramePen;
            }
        }
    }

    private Point[] RecalculateWindowFramePoints()
    {
        if ((WindowFrameType == Forms.WindowFrameType.AllSides)
            && (this.framePoints != null)
            && (this.framePoints.Length != 5))
        {
            this.framePoints = null;
        }
        if ((WindowFrameType == Forms.WindowFrameType.LeftLine)
            && (this.framePoints != null)
            && (this.framePoints.Length != 2))
        {
            this.framePoints = null;
        }
        if (this.framePoints == null)
        {
            switch (WindowFrameType)
            {
                case Forms.WindowFrameType.AllSides:
                    this.framePoints = new Point[5]
                    {
                        new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y),
                        new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X + this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Y),
                        new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X + this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Y + this.ClientRectangle.Height),
                        new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y + this.ClientRectangle.Height),
                        new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y)
                    };
                    break;
                case Forms.WindowFrameType.LeftLine:
                    this.framePoints = new Point[2]
                    {
                        new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y),
                        new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y + this.ClientRectangle.Height)
                    };
                    break;
            }
        }
        return this.framePoints;
    }

    private void DrawWindowFrame(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowFrameType == Forms.WindowFrameType.NoFrame)
        {
            return;
        }
        if ((this.framePoints == null) || (this.framePoints.Length == 0))
        {
            return;
        }
        Control ctrl = (Control)(sender);
        // пересчитаем точки в координатах контрола.
        List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();
        foreach (var p in this.framePoints)
        {
            pts.Add(ctrl.PointToClient(this.PointToScreen(p)));
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(ActivePen, pts.ToArray());
    }

    public static int WindowFrameSize = 2;
    public static WindowFrameType WindowFrameType = Forms.WindowFrameType.NoFrame;
    public static Color WindowFrameActiveColor = Color.YellowGreen;
    public static Color WindowFrameInactiveColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
    public static double InactiveWindowOpacity = 1.0;
    public static double WindowFrameOpacity = 0.3;
    #endregion
```

Static fields of the class are initialized from application settings form (class) - so, all the forms in the app has the same behavior.

Hope that helps to someone.

Comment: where can i find this type WindowFrameType??